# Lotus Notes user group's name in address book on different domain

Tags: email, lotus-notes

We have some problem with sending the emails to group within organization.

**The situation is :** Each sister plant have their own Domino Server.Somehow we have a similar group name for each plant. For example there is a group named as "Administrators" which also exist in other plant Domino address book. What we do to differentiate them is specifying Mail Domain which is unique for each plant.

**The problem is :** Sometimes there are users which is accidentally send the email to the group which is belong to other sister plant (by selecting the wrong domain) , even though Lotus Notes will prompt them to select the correct domain of the recipients.

May I know how to handle this situation ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this technically:

- You could set reader- fields to the different groups, so that only people from that NAB can route to that group (Key- Tab on the document properties)
- you could rename the groups to begin with a "unique" identifier: DOM1.Administrators, DOM2.Administrators
- Use a directory catalog to collect users of all addressbooks (and not groups) and use this in the directory assistance of the servers, so that people simply don't see the groups of other plants (or collect groups and make an agent to remove the duplicate ones)

But it doesn't matter, what you do technically, there will always be the possibility for users to circumvent your restrictions.

You better solve this organisationally by telling people what to do and what to stop doing.

Comment: sorry but cannot find this : Set reader- fields to the different groups, so  in the Hat- Tab on the document properties. btw I am using Lotus Notes 8.5, domino server 8.5.3.

Comment: Alt + Enter on any Group- Document. In the properties- dialog there is one tab with a little "propeller- hat". There you can restrict readers for a document. Take care: Don't forget to add LocalDomainServers and at least one Administrator- Group, otherwise the document will disappear...

Comment: maybe a tab with a Key icon ? yes, here we can select the reader but we need to select all user in the domain plus adding user if there us any new user. its quite hard to maintain, unless we can select which user we don't want to access the group.is there such way to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, it is the key- tab. You can add groups in that dialog, or values with placeholders (e.g. */CertOfOneCompany) but it is always a positive- list...